# how can i create a fork in c socket implementation?

Tags: c, sockets, fork

My mini project is on implementing a c socket program where multiple clients send files to two or three servers. i have implemented these. but for handling the client request i need to create a child process is it? how can i do that . like have to handle the request separately.please anybody guide me to do it.

Comment: While your client can connect to your server, it's because both use the same port number. But that port number is actually not what you think it is! It should be in network byte order, not in the native platforms byte order. Anyone else expecting that will not be able to connect to port `9734` as that's not the port number you actually use. Use e.g. `htons` when setting the port number: `address.sin_port = ntohs(9734);`

Comment: ok sir thank you. but where am i supposed to create fork. i mean in the server but i am confused where to exactly use it.

Comment: I don't think that you should use the fork model, it is from a different time. Use async IO.

Comment: i want to know how to create a child process.please somebody help me

Comment: @shishira You *have* seen my answer?

Comment: but if i use the below code. i get duplicate copies of the output!! m confused and not able to understand :(

Comment: but if i use the below code. i get duplicate copies of the output!! m confused and not able to understand

Answer (score 4):

The usual multi-process server would typically look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
passive_socket = create_listening_socket()

for (;;)
{
    new_socket = accept(passive_socket)
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        /* In child */
        read_from_socket(new_socket)
        write_to_socket(new_socket)
        /* Or do any other processing needed */

        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        /* In parent */
        close(new_socket)
    }
}
```